A-Frame: Weird rotation to two objects that is not in my code
// let me explain what the code does, there are two boxes, one blue and one green, when you click on the green box it causes the blue box to move in a circle in the air, there are 12 points on the circle, and each point is a case, while the blue boxes are moving both the blue and green boxes are rotating. This code works fine, what is the problem is that at the last rotation, when the blue box returns to it's starting point, there is a mysterious rapid 360 rotation of the blue box that is not in my code, and also the green box also rotates 360 degrees with no explanation. I looked on StackOverFlow, and In the Documentation, and on Discord, but I don't know what to call this problem, and you know it's hard to search when you don't know the name of the thing you are searching for. Any help as to what is causing this mysterious 360 rotation at the click reset point? I don't want it to have a mysterious 360 rotation marking that point as special somehow instead of being just the same as all the other points.
AFRAME.registerComponent("copy_rotation_scale_position", {
    init: function () {
      var rota = document.querySelector(".rota");
      var caller = document.querySelector("#caller");
      var clickCount = 0;
      let shouldScaleUp = true; // Keep track of scaling direction
      
      caller.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var rotation = caller.getAttribute("rotation");
        var position = caller.getAttribute("position");
        var scale = caller.getAttribute("scale");

        // Blue box rotation, position, and scale
        var angle = (clickCount * Math.PI) / 6 - Math.PI / 2; // Angle for each click (360 degrees / 12 clicks), offset by -90 degrees
        var newX, newY, newZ;

        switch (clickCount) {
          case 0:
            newX = 3;
            newY = 2;
            newZ = -3;
            break;
          case 1:
            newX = 2;
            newY = 2;
            newZ = -2;
            break;

          // case 2 through 10 you can just imagine

          case 11:
            newX = 2;
            newY = 2;
            newZ = -4;
            break;
          case 12:
            newX = 3;
            newY = 2;
            newZ = -3;
            break;
        }

        rota.setAttribute("animation", {
          property: "rotation",
          to: { x: (-angle * 180) / Math.PI, y: 0, z: 0 }, // Rotate to face the green box
          dur: 1000,
          shortestPath: true
        });
        rota.setAttribute("animation__2", {
          property: "position",
          to: { x: newX, y: newY, z: newZ }, // Move along the circular path above the green box
          dur: 500,
        });
        rota.setAttribute("animation__3", {
          property: "scale",
          from: { x: 0.01, y: 0.01, z: 0.01 }, // Start with a very small scale
          to: { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 }, // Expand to full size
          dur: 1000,
        });
        
        // Green box rotation and scale
        caller.setAttribute("animation", {
          property: "rotation",
          to: { x: (angle * 180) / Math.PI, y: 0, z: 0 }, // Rotate to face the blue box
          dur: 1000,
        });
        clickCount = (clickCount + 1) % 12; // Reset


It looks like the issue might be related to how you're handling the final case (case 12) in your switch statement. When clickCount reaches 12, it should reset to 0 to restart the animation sequence. However, it seems like you are resetting it to (clickCount + 1) % 12, which effectively resets it to 1 instead of 0.
To fix this issue, you should reset clickCount to 0 when it reaches 12. Here's the corrected line:
clickCount = (clickCount + 1) % 13; // Reset to 0 when it reaches 12

By changing % 12 to % 13, it ensures that clickCount cycles from 0 to 12 and then resets to 0, which should resolve the mysterious extra rotation at the end.
Additionally, make sure to adjust the case handling for case 12 to handle the final rotation properly.
Let me know if you need further assistance or if you encounter any other issues!

Oh right, I tried that 6 different variations of that idea, because 3 different AI programs suggested that idea, and the 360 spin still happens at the end of the last case, if I change the modulo to 13 in this instance the only difference is Case 12 happens, followed by Case 0, and in that situation means the object moves to the position in the 12th case, then when you click it, it still does the 360 rotation, but then it stays in the same position because Case 0 and Case 12 are identical. In another version of the code I just deleted Case 12, because it doesn't actually execute in this code.

but the 360 rotation still happens on the last case that executes regardless of what the modulo number is, and regardless of how many cases there are.

Update: I rebuilt the code in threejs using the anime js system, and I got the same error, it has to do with the tweening animation, apparently the rotation animation accumulates in memory, so when the case resets the previous animation is literally being unrolled backwards fast in order animate to the reset animation point. At this point in time I haven't identified a fix. I tried removing the rotation attribute but that hasn't worked (yet?)
